# Kotlin - How to split list of strings based on the total length of characters

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a program in Kotlin that is posting messages to a rest endpoint.

```
val messages : List<String> = getMessageToSend();
webClient
    .post()
    .uri { builder -> builder.path("/message").build() }
    .bodyValue(PostMessageRequest(
        messages.joinToString("\n")
    ))
    .exchange()
    .block()
```

However, the rest endpoint has a limit on the maximum size of messages sent. I'm fairly new to Kotlin, but I was looking for a functional way to achieve this, and i'm struggling. I know how I would write this in Java, but i'm keen to do it right. I want to split the `messages` list into a list of lists, with each list limited to the maximum size allowed and only whole strings added, and then post them individually. I've had a look at methods like `chunked`, but that doesn't seem flexible enough to achieve what i'm trying to do.

For example, if my message was `[this, is, an, example]` and the limit was 10, i'd expect my list of lists to be `[[this, is an], [example]]`

Any suggestions would be massively appreciated.

Comment: This is not a difficult problem, especially if you already know Java. Do it in Java. Then, once you have it working, find out about what better abstractions you could use in Kotlin; even the LINT analyzer will give you "hints" already. For what is worth, I don't think it's the job of this "object" here you're depicting, to "transform" the data. You should post the body "as is" in there. BUt you should have a data mapper/transformer that would grab the `List<Str>` and transform it into a `Map<...>`

Comment: So you first want to merge all the Strings of the initial list into one String, and then break it up into Strings of 10 chars or less? Is it okay to split in the middle of words?

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, we can't split in the middle of strings from the initial list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks rather like a situation I've hit before.  To solve it, I wrote the following general-purpose extension function:

```
/**
 * Splits a collection into sublists not exceeding the given size.  This is a
 * generalisation of [List.chunked]; but where that limits the _number_ of items in
 * each sublist, this limits their total size, according to a given sizing function.
 *
 * @param maxSize None of the returned lists will have a total size greater than this
 *                (unless a single item does).
 * @param size Function giving the size of an item.
 */
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.chunkedBy(maxSize: Int, size: T.() -> Int): List<List<T>> {
    val result = mutableListOf<List<T>>()
    var sublist = mutableListOf<T>()
    var sublistSize = 0L
    for (item in this) {
        val itemSize = item.size()
        if (sublistSize + itemSize > maxSize && sublist.isNotEmpty()) {
            result += sublist
            sublist = mutableListOf()
            sublistSize = 0
        }
        sublist.add(item)
        sublistSize += itemSize
    }
    if (sublist.isNotEmpty())
        result += sublist

    return result
}
```

The implementation's a bit hairy, but it's pretty straightforward to use.  In your case, I expect you'd do something like:

```
messages.chunkedBy(1024){ length + 1 }
        .map{ it.joinToString("\n") }
```

to give a list of strings, each no more than 1024 chars<sup>*</sup>.  (The `+ 1` is of course to allow for the newline characters.)

I'm surprised something like this isn't in the stdlib, to be honest.

<sup>(* Unless any of the initial strings is longer.)</sup>

Comment: Nice! Using it to chunk a long string, splitting on newlines:
`fun String.chunkedBy(delimiter: String, maxLength: Int) = split(delimiter).chunkedBy(maxLength + delimiter.length) { length + delimiter.length }.map { it.joinToString(delimiter) }`

Comment: Re the `messages.chunkedBy` example, using `length + 1` is right, but you end up accounting for 1-too-many newlines – adding 1 to `maxSize` fixes it: `messages.chunkedBy(1024 + 1) { length + 1 }.map { it.joinToString("\n") }`

Answer (score 1):

You can split a `List` into chunks of a given length by using [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) like this

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val messages = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    val chunks = messages.chunked(3)
    println("$messages ==> $chunks")
}
```

This prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ==> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I've added an example to hopefully make it a little clearer.

Comment: @BenGreen Do you want a list of lists where the sum of the length of the content of an inner list must not exceed a given limit? I don't think there's a built-in method for that, you will have to maintain a length counter or anything similar.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Ok thanks, I'm still fairly new to Kotlin, and so far it's seemed to have a shortcut for everything i've needed it to do, so I was just wondering if there was a better solution. I'll do it the old fashioned way for now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Really nice. For the fun of it I have written a more "Kotlin idiomatic" version of it.
The only complexity here is to put out also the remaining accumulator content when getting to the end of the list.

```
    fun <T> List<T>.chunkedBy(maxSize: Int, size: T.() -> Int) =
        sequence {
            runningFoldIndexed(emptyList<T>()) { index, acc, t ->
                with(acc + t) { if (sumOf(size) > maxSize) listOf(t).also { yield(acc) } else this }
                    .also { if (index == this@chunkedBy.size - 1) yield(it) }
            }
        }.toList()
```