# Chunk string by max size and at a whitespace only in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, split

I'm trying to write a `String` to a file where the maximumg record size is allowed to be a fixed size (e.g. 5). Moreover it's only allowed to be chunked at a whitespace (which is used as a seperator).

So let's say that is my string:

```
var myString = "ac de defgh a b c ghiz xy"
```

and i want to chunk it by size of 5 and join it with a line seperator, so it should be like this:

```
ac de \n
defgh \n
a b c \n
ghiz \n
xy \n
```

I tried to do this: `myString.chunked(5).joinToString(separator = "\n")`

but it will not chunk at whitespace but anywhere after 5 chars.

Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: To explain better, can you expand your example so it demonstrates the situation where your code doesn't work? And should chunking be greedy? For example, for input `"ab abcd"`, what should the result be?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It should not be greedy, so "ab abcd" should result in "ab \n abcd \n"... using my code "ab abcd" would result in "ab ab \n cd \n" (added whitespaces for better readability) and that is not what should happen ("abcd" is not allowed to be split into to lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split the string into words, group the words using a chunking function such as the one I gave in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63634737/10134209), then rejoin the words into lines and the lines into a string:

```
myString.split(" ")
        .chunkedBy(5 + 1){ length + 1 }
        .joinToString("\n"){ it.joinToString(" ") }
```

This gives the required result.  (Except for the trailing space at the end of each line, and the trailing newline at the end; if you really need them they'd be easy enough to add.)  I hope you can see how it works.

This approach isn't terribly efficient; it creates lots of temporary objects (for the words, their lists, and the resulting lines, as well as the final string), but it probably scales reasonably well, and it's relatively clear and concise.  You could almost certainly write a function that performed better, but it would be more complex, and specific to this particular task.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for - it seems to work like it should while the custom function is - as you mentioned in your post - a little bit hairy. I've hoped to find an easier solution (using a build-in kotlin function or something like that with less lines of code) - but it should do the trick. Thanks again for providing your solution